# Best practice for connecting to a TCP service with Play

Tags: scala, sockets, tcp

I want to connect to a locally running TCP service from a web application I'm building using the Play framework and scala.

I'm not sure how to open this connection and send commands to it, should I be writing raw socket code? Also, how should I be managing the connection? Can I just open the connection once and send commands from each web request to it? What if the connection is closed or falls over?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure Pay will be of much help here, most of its modules focus on HTTP communication. You should have a look at Akka-IO though.